# Searching for a range of dates in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a search through a table via LINQ and Entity Framework CORE.   I've got 2 text boxes startdate and enddate and a radio button set of 3 options created, modified and both.

This is the code I've produced based on Google searches and tutorials

```
       switch(radCreatedModifiedBoth) {
            case "b":
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate)) {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)) {
                        persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                        ps.CreatedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00") &&
                                                        ps.CreatedDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                        ) || (
                                                        ps.ModifiedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00") &&
                                                        ps.ModifiedDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                        )
                                                );
                    } else {
                        persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                        ps.CreatedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00")
                                                        ||
                                                        ps.ModifiedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00")
                                                      )
                                                );
                    }
                } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)) {
                    persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                    ps.CreatedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                    ||
                                                    ps.ModifiedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                  )
                                            );
                }
                break;
            case "c":
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate)) {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)) {
                        persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                        ps.CreatedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00") &&
                                                        ps.CreatedDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                        )
                                                );
                    } else {
                        persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                        ps.CreatedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00")
                                                      )
                                                );
                    }
                } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)) {
                    persons = persons.Where(ps <= (
                                                    ps.CreatedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                  )
                                            );
                }
                break;
            case "m":
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate)) {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)) {
                        persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                        ps.ModifiedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00") &&
                                                        ps.ModifiedDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                        )
                                                );
                    } else {
                        persons = persons.Where(ps => (
                                                        ps.ModifiedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00")
                                                      )
                                                );
                    }
                } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate)) {
                    persons = persons.Where(ps <= (
                                                    ps.ModifiedDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59")
                                                  )
                                            );
                }
                break;
        }
```

This code works but seems massively inefficient, not to mention adding the start and end time into the date as a string like this

```
startDate + " 00:00:00"
endDate + " 23:59:59"
```

just seems wrong.    Is this the prescribed method or can anyone suggest a more efficient method preferably getting rid of the " 00:00:00"/" 23:59:59"

Thanks

Comment: Try to post this in stackechange code review. I don't think you'll find what you want on SO.

Comment: Are your cases for when you have only an `endDate` backwards? If you have `startDate` and `endDate` you test to be between, but if you have just `startDate` or just `endDate`, you test both for greater?

Comment: Thanks, that'll serve me write for copying and pasting in a hurry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify by pushing the tests to SQL - the conditional operator will be translated to SQL `CASE WHEN` since they aren't simple constants. Note that I assumed you have the `endDate` tests backwards in your code sample. Also you have a lot of repeated sub-expressions I consolidated to variables. Since you are using EF Core, there isn't a better way to handle date only comparisons then what you are using. In EF you can use a DbFunction, but it still isn't as good as converting your dates to the appropriate date+time so that indices can be used.

```
var hasStartDate = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate);
var dtStartDate = hasStartDate ? Convert.ToDateTime(startDate + " 00:00:00") : DateTime.MinValue;

var hasEndDate = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate);
var dtEndDate = hasEndDate ? Convert.ToDateTime(endDate + " 23:59:59") : DateTime.MinValue;

var chkCreatedDate = (radCreatedModifiedBoth == "b" || radCreatedModifiedBoth == "c");
var chkModifiedDate = (radCreatedModifiedBoth == "b" || radCreatedModifiedBoth == "m");

persons = persons.Where(ps => (chkCreatedDate ? (hasStartDate ? ps.CreatedDate >= dtStartDate : true) && (hasEndDate ? ps.CreatedDate <= dtEndDate : true) : true)
                               ||
                              (chkModifiedDate ? (hasEndDate ? ps.ModifiedDate >= dtStartDate : true) && (hasEndDate ? ps.ModifiedDate <= dtEndDate : true) : true)
                        );
```

Comment: That seems much more sensible, I've upvoted but I'm too poor to have it show up :)
Thanks